# Send some arguments (like Ctrl-C, 3, some_string), to program, from bash script

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I have a program that written  in c++, and i have parameter that i want to re change. when the program is running.

So i have function that "catch" the signal INT, so when the program is running (in terminal) i type in terminal Ctrl-C, and this lead me to function with menu and the user can type 1,2,3 ... and then i type Enter and then  write some value (etc 123...).

Everything work well, but i want to do it automatically from bash script.

Hear is my code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
int val=0;
void signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
   printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
   // Cleanup and close up stuff here
   int ans = -1;  
   /*Print the menu.*/
   cout << "Press Your Choice"<<endl
        <<"MENU:"<<endl
        <<"1 - Exit."<<endl
        <<"2 - Resume."<<endl
        <<"3 - Add new computer."<<endl;

   cin >> ans;   
   switch (ans)
   {
       case 1: 
           exit(signum);
           break;
       case 2:
           cout <<" Resume"<< endl;
           break;
       case 3:
           //creat_new_clinet();
           cout<<"Option 3 choose"<<endl;
                     cout<<"Type value to val"<<endl;
                     cout<<"val before - "<<val<<endl;
                   cin>>val;
                   cout<<"val after - "<<val<<endl;
           break;
      default:
           break;                 
   }
}


 int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{    
    // Register signal and signal handler
    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    getchar();
}
```

i compiled it with g++ with flag "-std=c++11".

```
g++ temp.cpp -std=c++11 -o temp
```

After i compiled it i run it from terminal

```
  ./temp
```

So i type - Ctrl-C and then i got this message:

```
^CCaught signal 2 
Press Your Choice 
MENU: 
1 - Exit.
2 - Resume. 
3 - Add new computer.
```

Then i type 3, and here are  the result:

```
Option 3 choose
Type value to val
val before - 0
```

Then i type for example - 123, and the result is:

```
val after - 123
```

So i press on Enter and the program finish.
I want to do it automatically by bash script. i tried to do it with next script:

```
pgrep -f temp | xargs kill -INT 
pid_number=$(pidof temp)
echo $pid_number
arg='3\n'
echo $arg > /proc/$pid_number/fd/0
#xdotool key 3+Enter
#/usr/bin/xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[3]\[Enter]"
```

If i start the program (temp) and i run this script i can see the menu  but it doesen't do nothing, just show me the menu.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: If your program `temp` is running, what terminal is its standard input attached to?

Comment: I run it in ubuntu 16 and after i compile the temp i run it from standard  terminal.

Comment: And do you launch your script from the same standard terminal?

Comment: No i lunch temp in terminal in window 1, and i run the script in another window.

Comment: try [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Comment: i try to use with expect but as i don't know how to do it in my case because i start the program in one terminal and try to mange interrupt when the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate pressing the ENTER key, you have to send a Carriage return \r and not a newline \n